# AOT compiler generates wrong import

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-aot

I have a multi-app angular-cli project with some code base sharing.

Basically, the structure looks like following:

- **src** - main application

  - **app.component** - bootstrapped component
  - **app.module**
  - **shared** - shared application parts

    - **demo.component**
    - **shared.module**
- **extension** - second application supposed to extend the main one

  - **extension-app.component** - bootstrapped component
  - **extension.module**

`SharedModule` (which declares and exports the `DemoComponent`) is imported by both `AppModule` and `ExtensionModule`. `DemoComponent` is then added to templates of both `AppComponent` and `ExtensionAppComponent`.

Everything is working just fine when using JIT compiler (`ng serve`, `ng serve --app extension`), but AOT compiler fails saying:

`Can't resolve '../../../src/app/demo/demo.component.ngfactory'`

Looking into this generated file at `GENDIR/app/demo/demo.component.ngfactory` we get the following:

```
import * as i0 from './demo.component.css.shim.ngstyle';
import * as i1 from '@angular/core';
import * as i2 from './demo.component';
```

The last one import is the one that fails, because there is no 'demo.component' in the `GENDIR/app/demo` folder. Surprisingly the file imported as `i0` does exist and contains appropriate styles.

*UPDATE: looks like the problem is in `ngc`. It would neither work even if you add a `paths` alias in `tsconfig.json`. There are a couple of issues about it on github (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13487)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue today, and I was able to resolve it by moving my `tsconfig.app.json` file into an ancestor directory of all the code I wanted to use.  I then modified the `include` array in my `tsconfig.app.json` to only include the secondary app.

**NOTE:** I was using a single `.angular-cli.json` configured to build multiple apps. If you have multiple configurations, your mileage may vary

For your example, you could try the following structure:

- **<parent directory>**

  - **src** (main application)

    - **app.component** - bootstrapped component
    - **app.module**
    - **shared** - shared application parts

      - **demo.component**
      - **shared.module**
  - **extension** - second application supposed to extend the main one

    - **extension-app.component** - bootstrapped component
    - **extension.module**
  - **tsconfig.extension.json** - app-specific tsconfig file for your extension application

In your `tsconfig.extension.json` file, add an include section:

```
...
"include": [
    "./extension/**/*"
]
...
```

Assuming you have each app declared in your `.angular-cli.json` file, you'll also need to update the `"tsconfig"` property for your extension application:

```
"name": "extension",
// Other configuration...
"tsconfig": <insert path to tsconfig based on "root" here>
```

*READER BEWARE*
This structure is kind of a hack, and is not officially supported.  Don't be surprised if a future update causes this to collapse on itself!

Working on:

- Node:           v8.4.0
- npm:            5.4.2
- @angular/cli:   1.4.2